# Telerik RadPanorama control in a WindowsFormsHost control

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, telerik, windowsformshost

I am building a WPF app where I work and I want to use the RadPanorama for the Start Screen or "Launching Pad" for the App.  I understand, and have seen the numerous threads, that there is no RadPanorama for WPF.

However, is there any reason I cannot embed one in a WindowsFormsHost?

Seems to work after a VERY quick little test but I am wondering if anyone has any feedback on doing it this way?  Somethings are very 'messy' to get at with out the Design Time support.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This control will work just like any other Window Forms control used in WPF app via host. You can use groups which can hold items, or just add the desired items to the control without a group.